# running basic commands all at once and then sequentially after they all finish

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing, command

How would I run several commands as below so that the last line executes (cleans up) after all the background ones are done?

```
echo "oyoy 1" > file1 &
echo "yoyoyo 2" > file2 &
rm -f file1 file2
```

Of course the echo commands are different for me and take a long time to finish (I can delete the files manually or with another script I know, but I was wondering how to have this done in one script..)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?wait)

```
 wait [n ...]
      Wait  for each specified process and return its termination sta-
      tus.  Each n may be a process ID or a job  specification;  if  a
      job  spec  is  given,  all  processes in that job's pipeline are
      waited for.  If n is not given, all currently active child  pro-
      cesses  are  waited  for,  and  the return status is zero.  If n
      specifies a non-existent process or job, the  return  status  is
      127.   Otherwise,  the  return  status is the exit status of the
      last process or job waited for.
```

So you can wait for the baackground processes to finish like this:

```
echo "oyoy 1" > file1 &
echo "yoyoyo 2" > file2 &
wait
rm -f file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you have a bunch of things you are running and you only need to wait for a few processes to complete you can store a list of pids and then only wait for those.

```
echo "This is going to take forever" > file1 &
mypids=$!
echo "I don't care when this finishes" > tmpfile &
echo "This is going to take forever also" >file2 &
mypids="$mypids $!"
wait $mypids
```